# Replace a string in MySQL in a specific field depending on the value of another field

Tags: mysql, wordpress, replace, bbpress

How can I find and replace in MySQL depending on the values of another field? For example,

I want to replace all of the "0" values in the column "post_parent" with "126810"...but only if those entries also have a value of "topic" in the "post_type" field.

I thought it would be something like this but it doesn't seem to work, syntax issues and all:

```
update wp_posts set post_parent = replace(post_parent,`0`,`126810`) 
WHERE `post_type` LIKE 'topic');
```

I also guess that even if I could have gotten that to work, I would have **replaced all post_parent values of 10, 20, 30, etc. with 1126810, 2126810, etc.**

Anyone happen to know how I could solve both of those issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to extend your `WHERE` clause:

```
update wp_posts 
set post_parent = replace(post_parent,0,126810)
WHERE post_type = 'topic'
  AND post_parent = 0;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4a62/1)

Comment: I'll accept the answer in 5 minutes, apparently as a newbaroo it's not cool for my question to be answered and tested so quickly. :)

Comment: @Nathan happy to help, you were vey close to the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a `case when` would help you.

```
update wp_posts 
set post_parent = 
case when (`post_type` LIKE 'topic'
and post_parent = `0`)
then
replace(post_parent,`0`,`126810`)
end
```

;